# how to use Navigation drawer activity as launcher activity of a salesforce template App

Tags: android, oop, salesforce, navigation-drawer, multiple-inheritance

i am creating an android native app with salesforce and i am new to this, also i may be loosing any OOPS concept, so here is the problem

I am using the salesforceSDK provided by force.com and building a template App that from the library extends and activity

And it uses a rough layout, i want to replace it with a NavDrawer activity that extends AppCompatActivity,
but when i go and extend the basic SalesforceActivity with the AppcompatActivity instead the Activity, it makes this trouble[The problem is show in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pnBX.png)

One has to extend the SalesforceActivity to gain access to salesforce.com,

I want to access salesforceActivity and AppCompatActivity's feature at the same time(Multiple Inheritence)
So please help me with this question
thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a link to template mobile SDK if someone might want to download and test it before answering me  [Salesforce mobile sdk on github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/native/TemplateApp)

Comment: And another link is here that will describe how to use sdk, Someone please help me,  [Getting started with mobile sdk](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/mobile_sdk_intro/mobile_sdk_native_android/mobilesdk_android_getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a long research i found a way to get rid of the problem

Instead of using activity extending AppCompatActivity and than implementing a NavDrawer, I managed to find the External Library for awesome looking and popular NavDrawer with really quick and easy setup.

Here is the link :https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer